# How to redirect Sub directory to Parent directory in mod-rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This's my sub domain that I'm working now.

```
project.mywebsite.com/{shopname}
```

But there's a URL Segment parameter on URL, By ***shopname*** is URL Segment parameter *isn't  existence directory.* It use to be a parameter and send to Core programs to acknowledge what database use.

I have a another domain that point to

```
project.mywebsite.com/{shopname}/domains/sitename/index.html
```

And I'd like to redirect this URL that store in Sub directory to Parent URL *(project.mywebsite.com/{shopname})* together with URL segment parameter.

How can I write **mod-rewrite** in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/domains/sitename/index\.html$ /$1
```

Comment: Thank you for help me but sorry, It didn't work, I place .htaccess file in **coreprogram path/domains/sitename**.

The domain's not regonize anything.

`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteBase /`
`RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/domains/sitename/index\.html$ /$1`

Is there another way else?.

Comment: @KKK it needs to be placed in the document root